# VBA Excel error with Button objects .OnAction

Tags: excel, vba

My job we have a lot of reports that's generated. Using a modular approach I'm trying to set up a Excel workbook that dynamically creates sheets based on what report that's picked from Sheet("MainMenu")

Anyways, in the dynamic sheet I have the following

```
Public Sub OFFD_Report_Parse()
   Init 'just declares workbook and worksheet globals

   If shtTCL.Visible = False Then shtTCL.Visible = True
   shtTCL.Activate
   shtMenu.Visible = False
        
   Dim rngBtn1, rngBtn2, rngBtn3, rngBtn4 As Range
   Dim btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 As Button

   Set rngBtn1 = shtTCL.Range("B10")
   Set btn1 = shtTCL.Buttons.Add(rngBtn1.Left, rngBtn1.Top, rngBtn1.Width, rngBtn1.Height)
   With btn1
    .OnAction = "TCL1"
    .Caption = "Copy 1"
   End With
```

When ran I get Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the OnAction property of the Button Class

The sub it's calling:

```
Sub TCL1()
     Clipboard ("SELECT ORDER WITH FLAG.DELETE = " & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & Chr(13))
     CopyMsg 
End Sub
```

Is in the same module. I've used this exact method of code in another excel file with no issues which is really making me stumped.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to solve your problem.

1. The code must be in a standard module, not the sheet-behind
2. You can't have a numeric suffix on the action

I also notice that you're trying to dim a bunch of variables instead of using an array or collection. Only dim one variable per line. Each variable needs the `As` statement. Those that are omitted are declared as a variant by default.

If you use a collection you can dynamically generate the array without knowing how many elements it will have up front.

Where I explicitly call out the index of the collection `(0)` you could instead use a loop and a loop counter.

EXAMPLE:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OFFDReportParse()
    Init 'just declares workbook and worksheet globals
    
    If shtTCL.Visible = False Then shtTCL.Visible = True
    shtTCL.Activate
    shtMenu.Visible = False
         
    Dim buttonRanges As Collection
    Dim newButtons As Collection
    
    buttonRanges.Add shtTCL.Range("B10")
    newButtons.Add shtTCL.Buttons.Add(buttonRanges(0).Left, buttonRanges(0).Top, buttonRanges(0).Width, buttonRanges(0).Height)
    With newButtons(0)
        .OnAction = "TCLaction"
        .Caption = "Copy 1"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub TCLaction()
     Clipboard ("SELECT ORDER WITH FLAG.DELETE = " & Chr(34) & "Y" & Chr(34) & Chr(13))
     CopyMsg
End Sub
```